# Next.JS/React Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, fetch

**TL;DR** 
I have an error `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])` due to a fetch request in the code. The project is written in Typescript and when I try the same code snippet in another project (Javascript), I don't get the error.

So I have been working on a project and when I try to send a POST request via fetch, I get the error
`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`. I think that the metadata in the fetch method is causing this error, but I don't think that there is a way around it. I checked if it was just an error so I compared it to another request in one of my other projects, and it copied its code to my current project. And I still got the same error! Could it be because my current project is written in typescript?

```js
// This is Typescript
//It's also the same code as my other project.

import axios from 'axios';
export default async function component() {
  const uri = "http://localhost:3000"
  const data = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  }
  async function sendRequest() {
     await fetch(`${uri}/api/getPasswords`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({data}),
    }).then(e => {
      console.log(e);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={sendRequest}>Send POST request</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `async` in `export default async function component()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, you are using `async` on your **React component**. Follow these steps:

1. Remove `async` keyword from the React component
2. Make the component name start with uppercase (component -> Component)
3. Use `axios` instead of `fetch` and use trycatch (*optional*)

```js
import axios from 'axios'

async function sendRequest() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`${uri}/api/getPasswords`, data)
    console.log(res.data)
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not related to Typescript, you're trying to use a Promise as a React Component, first, resolve the Promise and then send the data you need as a proper React Component.